# Rails: uploading files with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, permissions, paperclip

I would like to use paperclip to upload files. With the basic out of the box settings, I was able to get the file uploaded to the default directory (something in public/systems...) However when I tried changing the url or path (or both):

```
class Cvit < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :fileup, :path => ":rails_root/public/data/01_fasta"
end
```

I lose permission to the 01_fasta directory, after doing a chmod 777 on it, I notice the file is there but its named something like, stream20110706-45944-12lt2oo-0

also tried #{rails_root} in place of :rails_root.

Whats the deal????

**SOLVED**: the :url and :path need to point at a file, not a directory. So I had to have something like

```
class Cvit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :fileup,
    :url => "/data/01_fasta/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/data/01_fasta/:basename.:extension"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the :url and :path need to point at a file, not a directory. So I had to have something like

```
class Cvit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :fileup,
    :url => "/data/01_fasta/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/data/01_fasta/:basename.:extension"
end
```

Comment: So you can uplaod files to custom directories in rails?

Answer (score 3):

```
 has_attached_file :doc, :path => ":rails_root/public/system/attachments/:id/:filename"


def filename
"/system/attachments/#{self.id}/#{self.doc_file_name}"
end
```

works for me