# Saving textarea input as an attachment using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, paperclip

I want to be able to input text to a textarea element and save that text as an attachment using paperclip. I'm only familiar with using

```
<input type="file" />
```

for saving things with paperclip. Is it possible to create a file programmatically and then upload it using paperclip?

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip (https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/paperclip) is a really great gem/plugin for Ruby on Rails that makes handling file attachments super easy.

Follow this link to find out How to upload files using PaperClip :
http://runnable.com/UnnhcBiQoFhwAAEb/how-to-upload-files-using-paperclip-for-ruby-on-rails

These may be also helpful :
[Paper clip files upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873292/paper-clip-files-upload)
[Rails: uploading files with paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611624/rails-uploading-files-with-paperclip)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I looked at this, but I remember that I found a solution. I had a weird problem with paperclip when creating a file with write access. My solution was to create the file, close it, and then reopen it with read access. This works, but feels wrong. If anyone can improve on this feel free to post your solution.

```
my_object = MyObject.new
file = File.new('my_file.txt', 'w')
file.write(params[:my_textarea].to_s)
file.close
file = File.open('my_file.txt')
my_object.css = file
file.close
my_object.save
```